# Number of the same values per day

Tags: php, sql, count

Do I need to advise how can I calculate the specified number of values for the given day from my database?

In the database I have this:

```
title      cas     datum
Karel      9-14    2017-07-06
Petr       9-14    2017-07-06
Kuba       14-19   2017-07-06
Ivo        9-14    2017-07-04
```

And the result is to calculate how many times it is. Example 9-14 on 2017-07-06 Answer: 2

I tried it like this, but it lists all the values in the table and with another date.

```
$cas = '14-19';
$result = $db->query("SELECT Count(datum) as r FROM events WHERE cas = '".$cas."'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['r'];
```

Comment: what do you mean with "values in the table and with another date."?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the date condition to your sql

notice the `AND datum = ?` in the SQL statement

```
$cas = "9-14";
$datum = "2017-07-06";

$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(datum) AS r FROM events WHERE cas = ? AND datum = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
!$stmt ? die('error') : "";
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $cas, $datum);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row['r'];
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You didn't put the `datum` in the WHERE clause. That's probably why it's showing you another date.

```
$cas = '14-19';
$datum = '2017-07-06'; 
result = $db->query("SELECT Count(datum) as r FROM events WHERE cas = '".$cas."' AND datum = '".$datum."'");
```

2) Do you want to have to specify the `datum` and the `cas` ? If not, look into the GROUP BY clause.

```
result = $db->query("SELECT datum, cas, Count(*) as r FROM events GROUP BY datum, cas");
```